# ASP.NET Date Validation

Tags: c#, asp.net

How to check that entered date is less than or not in 22nd of every month in a calendar, if I choose 23 then give me an error message in asp.net

```
<tr>
    <td>Select Date:</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>
        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtdate" runat="server"  CssClass="form-control" placeholder="yyyy-mm-dd" ForeColor="Black" required="true"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:CalendarExtender ID="CalExt" runat="server" CssClass="cal_Theme1" TargetControlID="txtdate" PopupButtonID="txtdate" Format="yyyy-MM-dd" />
    </td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
```

This is my front-end code and please help to how to solve this

Comment: What error message do you get?

Answer (score 0):

You might be looking for:

```
<ajaxToolkit:CalendarExtender ID="CalExt" runat="server" CssClass="cal_Theme1" TargetControlID="txtdate" PopupButtonID="txtdate" Format="yyyy-MM-dd" />
```

Instead of "<asp:CalendarExtender"

After you make that change, you can work out how to validate the date the user selects, which may require you to write a custom validator.